# Display a quick maintenance page (but still allow myself access to the application) - quick fix

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want a really quick fix to prevent all access to a website unless a url has `dev=passcode` in it.

I tried creating a BaseController:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{                
    public BaseController()
    {            
        if( Request.Params[ "dev" ] != "something" )
        {
            this.MaintenancePage();
        }
    }

    public ActionResult MaintenancePage()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

and then every other controller comes off of it.

```
class HomeController : BaseController
{
    private IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    public HomeController( IUnitOfWork uow ){..}

    public ActionResult Index(){...}
}
```

The issue is that at the BaseController the Request is null at this point.

Any quick fixes?

Comment: You can actually add a .NET URL Rewrite rule (which will be in the IIS level). You can do it either in the IIS Manager UI or define it your app's web.config.

Comment: @Y.S - Can you give me an example :) ?

Comment: Try using `Action Filters` http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs That is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `OnActionExecuting`. Here the `Request` will be already created and the `OnActionExecuting` will be called before any actions in the controller.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{                
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string actionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
        if( Request.Params["dev"] != "something" && !String.Compare(actionName, "MaintenancePage", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("MaintenancePage");
        }
    }

    public ActionResult MaintenancePage()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**Note:** You can move this behaviour in an Action filter if fits better.

Comment: Any way to prevent the controller loop that is caused?

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 Thank you for showing me this, I updated my answer. You can access the action name inside `OnActionExecuting`.

Comment: It needs to be lower case on the actionName check. Thanks man, this allw orks great.

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 I'm glad that you solved the problem. In the condition or redirect?

Comment: The condition. `actionName != "maintenancepage"`